# Laravel not saving the timezone offset on a datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timezone, php-carbon

### The problem - timezone not being saved

I have a datetime column on my MYSQL database called `starts_at`. When I try to save a Carbon date with a timezone e.g. `2021-12-31 13:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)`, the record successfully saves.

But when I query the record again, I see that ***the timezone was not saved***.

Instead I see `"2021-12-31 13:00:00"` i.e. the UTC (+00:00) was not saved.

I want it to be explicit that the datetimes in this column are in UTC.

### Code snippet

Here is an example of what is happening:

```php
// 1. Create a Carbon object that has a timezone of UTC
$first_of_jan_sydney = Carbon::create(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'Australia/Sydney');
$first_of_jan_sydney->setTimezone('UTC');

// => Carbon\Carbon @1640955600 {#4471
//      date: 2021-12-31 13:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),
//    }


// 2. Set the starts_at field to the Carbon object
$food_item_availability = FoodItemAvailability::first();
$food_item_availability->starts_at = $first_of_jan_sydney;
$food_item_availability->save();

// 3. When I requery the starts_at column, I see that the timezone (UTC) was not saved
FoodItemAvailability::first()->starts_at; // "2021-12-31 13:00:00"
```

### Migration

In the migration that created the table, I used `dateTimeTz` e.g.

```php
$table->dateTimeTz('starts_at')->nullable();
```

### Config

In my `app.php`, I have set the timezone e.g.

```php
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

In my `database.php`, I have set the timezone e.g.

```php
        'mysql' => [
            // ...
            'timezone'  => '+00:00',
        ],
```

Comment: You are saving the date as UTC, your database is configured to UTC, and the date you retrieve is UTC. What's the problem? You saved '2021-12-31 13:00:00' and that's what you got out.

Comment: I tried to save "2021-12-31 13:00:00+00:00" but got back "2021-12-31 13:00:00" (timezone was lost)

Comment: That's not how dates are stored by mysql, which is largely timezone agnostic. It assumes dates are in the timezone it's configured for, and so should you. Unless you change the configured timezone on a database server with existing data in it, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, are you properly casting the column to a date in your model definition? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 2):

`dateTimeTz` and `timestampTz` are sadly not supported by all DB engines, MySQL does not for instance. So you have to store it in 2 columns from your side.

Actually it can help having a better control application-side and avoid relying on DB for timezone handling which is IMO better.

I recommend:

```php
$table->dateTime('starts_at')->nullable();
$table->string('starts_at_timezone')->nullable();
```

Here I use `CarbonImmutable` instead of `Carbon` so the timezone isn't modified on the original object. You can also use `->copy()` but `CarbonImmutable` is generally the safest way to work with dates:

```php
$first_of_jan_sydney = CarbonImmutable::parse('2022-01-01 00:00 Australia/Sydney');


$food_item_availability = FoodItemAvailability::first();
$food_item_availability->starts_at_timezone = $first_of_jan_sydney->tzName;
$food_item_availability->starts_at = $first_of_jan_sydney->utc();
$food_item_availability->save();

// Reload later:
$item = FoodItemAvailability::first();
CarbonImmutable::parse($item->starts_at, 'UTC')->tz($item->starts_at_timezone);
```

PS: Keep UTC and +00:00 as global settings, this part is fine. If you keep it, you can use `CarbonImmutable::parse($item->starts_at)->tz($item->starts_at_timezone);` without having to specify explicitly the `'UTC'` as timezone parameter.

Comment: Seems like using a mutator/accessor would be cleaner for storing and retrieving the date and time zone together. Also worth noting that this is only needed if you have to store dates from multiple time zones in the database.

Comment: If OP would have wanted to always restore dates as 'Australia/Sydney' I don't think this question would have even needed to be asked.

I also think it's good to keep datetime and timezone info separated, as you might not always need to get both together.